# Submenu size in navigation bar using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, navigationbar

I am trying to create a website, but i'm having a strange problem wiht my submenu in nav bar as you can see in this picture:

**submenu problem**

[image]

What I want is that my submenus elements have the same size, so I mean the same height.

This is my HTML part:

```
<header>
            <div class="menu_bar">
                <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a>
            </div>

            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png"> 
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Type...">
                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Search">            
                </form>
            </div> 

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-home"></span>Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-briefcase"></span>Cities</a></li>
                    <li class="tete">
                        <a href="#"><span class="icon-rocket"></span>Activites<span class="flash icon-circle-down"</a>
                        <ul class="sousmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Venice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Rome</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pisa</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-earth"></span>Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-envelop"></span>Contacter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

And this is CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;}



body {
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-x:hidden;}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;}


.menu_bar {
    display:none;}

header {
    width: 100%;}

header nav {
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index:1000;
    max-width: 1400px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 0px; }

header nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin-left: 220px;}


.logo{
    float: left;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;}


.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.5%;
    left: 95%;
    width: 700px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   }

input{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s}

input[type="text"]
{
    background: #fff;
    opacity:0.2;
    width: 270px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 25px;
    border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;   }


input[type="submit"]
{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0; 
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffc107;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    background: #ff5722;} 

header nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;}

header nav ul li:hover {
    background:red;}

header nav ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 20px;}

header nav ul li a span {
    margin-right:10px;}

header nav ul li:hover .sousmenu {
    display:block;}

header nav ul li .sousmenu {
    display: none;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 150%;
    z-index:1000;}

header nav ul li .sousmenu li {
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5); }

header nav ul li .sousmenu li a {
    padding: 10px; 
    display: block;}

/*header nav ul li .sousmenu li a span {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top:3px;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:10px;
}*/

header nav ul li .flash {
    position: relative;
    top:1px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:0px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        padding-top:80px;
    }

    .menu_bar {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        background:#E6344A;
    }

    .menu_bar .bt-menu {
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu_bar span {
        float: right;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    header nav {
        width: 80%;
        height: calc(100% - 80px);
        position: fixed;
        right:100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    header nav ul{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }


    header nav ul li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }

    header nav ul li a {
        display: block;
    }

    sheader nav ul li:hover .sousmenu {

        display: none;
    }

    header nav ul li .sousmenu {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    header nav ul li .sousmenu li a {
        margin-left:20px;
    }

    header nav ul li .flash {
        float: right;
    }

    .logo 
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .box input
    {
        display: none;  
    }
}
```

This is JS part:

```
$(document).ready(main);
var contador = 1;
function main(){
    $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
        // $('nav').toggle(); 

        if(contador == 1){
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '0'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        }

    });

    // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
    $('.tete').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.sousmenu').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not see your all code but you can try something like this to play with your li or ul

```
header nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
}
```

Or

```
header nav ul li {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole page code with css an JS? please!

Comment: It's too long for a comment!

Comment: Edit your question then!

Comment: Ok did it! I woudl be so grateful if you could fix it!

Comment: Still i have to see your HTML and you JS?,, you edited just the css.. i will try to help you?!

Comment: the html is all i have according the nav bar. Right now i'll putting the js

Comment: I answered you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to close a ">" the correct code:

```
  <header>
        <div class="menu_bar">
            <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a>
        </div>

        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo.png"> 
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Type...">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Search">            
            </form>
        </div> 

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-home"></span>Acceuil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-briefcase"></span>Cities</a></li>
                <li class="tete">
       <a href="#"><span class="icon-rocket"></span>Activites<span class="flash icon-circle-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="sousmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Venice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rome</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pisa</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-earth"></span>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-envelop"></span>Contacter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```